# How can I Generate specified strings in VBA with assigned probabilities?

Tags: vba, excel

For example: I have a car in London and it can go to Oxford in 60% of cases, to Liverpool in 30% and to Cardiff in 10%.

I'd like an help about how writing the VBA code for having a result like this, writing destination strings according to the percentages written previously :

```
From           To      
London         Cardiff
From           To
London         Liverpool
From           To
London         Liverpool
From           To
London         Oxford
From           To
London         Oxford  
From           To
London         Oxford
```

Comment: a reasonable question IMHO, though downvoters might object it sounds like you want us to write your code.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have VBA skills and I have to generate a database for Microsoft Access with over 111000 records. I've only basic knowledges about this code Language..I'm just praying for a little help ;)

Comment: 111000? that is pertinent information, do you really have this many different outcomes or are you exaggerating?

Comment: 111000 for each month..I have to distribute the logistic network of a big italian food company..

Answer (score 1):

I specified my probabilities like that:

```
     A          B       C
1  Liverpool  Oxford  Cardiff
2  60         30      10
```

and used this code (explanation in comments):

```
'this option makes declaration of variables mandatory, which prevents from mistyping mistakes
Option Explicit
Sub GenerateRoutes()
    'declaration of variables
    Dim probTable As Variant, sheet1 As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long, howManyRowToGenerate As Long, startRow As Long, endRow As Long
    howManyRowToGenerate = 100
    'always set reference to sheet, also, prevents from many mistakes
    Set sheet1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    'here you have use range that you have probabilities assigned
    probTable = sheet1.Range("A1:C2").Value2
    'clear specified range
    sheet1.Range("A1:C2").Clear
    sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value = "From"
    sheet1.Cells(1, 2).Value = "To"
    'using values from given table, generate rows
    startRow = 1
    For i = LBound(probTable, 2) To UBound(probTable, 2)
        endRow = startRow + howManyRowToGenerate * probTable(2, i) / 100 - 1
        For j = startRow To endRow
            sheet1.Cells(j + 1, 1).Value = "London"
            sheet1.Cells(j + 1, 2).Value = probTable(1, i)
        Next
        startRow = j
    Next
End Sub
```

which produces:

```
     A       B
1  From    To
2  London  Liverpool
3  London  Liverpool
4  London  Liverpool
etc.
62 London  Oxford
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a simulation class or some such but actually your volume/scale requirements put this less sensible for VBA

So I've written a class to get you started, I called in EventSpace

```
Option Explicit

Private m_dicOutcomes As New Scripting.Dictionary
Private m_dicCumulativeCalc As New Scripting.Dictionary
Private m_dicSimulation As New Scripting.Dictionary

Private m_alCumulProbsOptimized() As Double
Private m_lCount As Long

Private m_lIterations As Long


Public Function ReportResults() As String()

    Dim asReport() As String

    ReDim asReport(0 To m_dicSimulation.Count) As String


    Dim lOutcomeLoop As Long
    For lOutcomeLoop = 0 To m_dicSimulation.Count - 1

        asReport(lOutcomeLoop) = m_dicOutcomes.Keys()(lOutcomeLoop) & vbTab & ": " & (m_dicSimulation.Item(lOutcomeLoop) / m_lIterations)


    Next

    ReportResults = asReport

End Function

Public Function RunSimulation(ByVal lIterations As Long) As Scripting.Dictionary

    m_lIterations = lIterations
    CopyCumulativeProbsToArray

    Dim lLoop As Long
    For lLoop = 1 To lIterations

        Dim lOutCome As Long
        lOutCome = CalcOutcomeFromCumul(Rnd(1))

        m_dicSimulation.Item(lOutCome) = m_dicSimulation.Item(lOutCome) + 1

    Next lLoop

    Set RunSimulation = m_dicSimulation

End Function

Friend Function CalcOutcomeFromCumul(ByVal dblRandom As Double) As Long

    'Dim lLoop2 As Long

    Dim lLoop As Long
    For lLoop = 0 To m_lCount

        If dblRandom < m_alCumulProbsOptimized(lLoop) Then
            CalcOutcomeFromCumul = lLoop
            GoTo SingleExit
        End If

    Next
SingleExit:


End Function

Friend Sub CopyCumulativeProbsToArray()

    m_lCount = m_dicCumulativeCalc.Count - 1

    ReDim m_alCumulProbsOptimized(0 To m_lCount) As Double

    '* copy to an array
    Dim vItems As Variant
    vItems = m_dicCumulativeCalc.Items

    Dim lLoop As Long
    For lLoop = 0 To m_lCount

        m_alCumulProbsOptimized(lLoop) = vItems(lLoop)

    Next

End Sub

Public Sub AddOutcome(ByVal sName, ByVal dblProbavbility As Double)

    If m_dicOutcomes.Exists(sName) Then Err.Raise vbObjectError, , "#Outcome already added!"

    m_dicOutcomes.Add sName, dblProbavbility

End Sub


Public Function CalcCumulative() As Boolean
    Dim vKeyLoop As Variant
    Dim dblCumulative As Double: dblCumulative = 0
    For Each vKeyLoop In m_dicOutcomes
        Dim dblProb As Double
        dblProb = m_dicOutcomes.Item(vKeyLoop)

        dblCumulative = dblCumulative + dblProb
        m_dicCumulativeCalc.Item(vKeyLoop) = dblCumulative
    Next
End Function

Public Function IsFullDefined() As Boolean

    Me.CalcCumulative

    Dim dblFinalCumulative As Double
    dblFinalCumulative = m_dicCumulativeCalc.Items()(m_dicCumulativeCalc.Count - 1)
    If (dblFinalCumulative - 1) < 0.0001 Then
        IsFullDefined = True
    End If

End Function
```

And some test code for a standard module

```
Option Explicit


Sub TestEventSpace()

    Randomize

    Dim oEventSpace As EventSpace
    Set oEventSpace = New EventSpace
    oEventSpace.AddOutcome "Oxford", 0.6
    oEventSpace.AddOutcome "Liverpool", 0.3
    oEventSpace.AddOutcome "Cardiff", 0.1

    Debug.Assert oEventSpace.IsFullDefined

    Dim dicSimulationResults As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dicSimulationResults = oEventSpace.RunSimulation(1000)

    Debug.Print Join(oEventSpace.ReportResults, vbNewLine)


End Sub
```

From there you can wire it into the worksheet with some of your own code.